# Logging error in OWIN hosted Web API

Tags: logging, owin, katana

Is there an easy way to have a kind of global error trap that logs all unhandled errors in an OWIN hosted Web API ? Kind of like when you declare a global error trap in Global.asax. I must say the documentation of the Microsoft.Owin.Logging namespace is quite thin.

I've checked these excellent samples on OWIN [here](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/OwinSamples). But I still have to catch the exception and call the logger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global exception handling in OWIN middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479465/global-exception-handling-in-owin-middleware)