# Owin WebApi service ignoring ExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-apicontroller

Stack,

For some reason my Owin WebApi service is ignoring our custom exception handler. I'm following documentation for [asp.net exception handling](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling). Here are the simplified implementation details (scrubbed out business proprietary stuff).

Can you someone point out what I'm overlooking?

**Custom exception filter:**

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
   {
       actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
       actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new StringContent("...my custom business...message...here...");
   }
}
```

**During startup:**

```
var filter = new CustomExceptionFilter();
config.Filters.Add(filter);
appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
```

**Test controller:**

```
[CustomExceptionFilter]
public class TestController: ApiController
{
    public void Get()
    {
        throw new Exception(); // This is a simplification. 
                               // This is really thrown in buried 
                               // under layers of implementation details
                               // used by the controller.
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a project that does this exact pattern, except in the OnException to modify the response I `throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(...` instead of modifying the `actionExecutedContext`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to implement [Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling).
This way you will get a global error handler for Web API middleware, but not for other middlewares in OWIN pippeline, like authorization one.

If you want to implement a globlal error handling middleware, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31097878/2054754), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34312016/2054754) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34493054/2054754) links could orientate you.

I hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Regarding on @t0mm13b's comment, I'll give a little explanation based on the first [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31097878/2054754) link from [Khanh TO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1957251/khanh-to).

For global error handling you can write a custom and simple middleware that just pass the execution flow to the following middleware in the pipeline but inside a `try` block.

If there is an unhandled exception in one of the following middlewares in the pipeline, it will be captured in the `catch` block:

```
public class GlobalExceptionMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public GlobalExceptionMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    { }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // your handling logic
        }
    }
}
```

In the `Startup.Configuration()` method, add the middleware in first place to the pipeline if you want to handle exceptions for all other middlewares.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use<GlobalExceptionMiddleware>();
        //Register other middlewares
    }
}
```

As pointed by [Tomas Lycken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38055/tomas-lycken) in the second [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34312016/2054754) link, you can use this to handle exceptions generated in Web API middleware creating a class that implements `IExceptionHandler` that just throws the captured exception, this way the global exception handler middleware will catch it:

```
public class PassthroughExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // don't just throw the exception; that will ruin the stack trace
        var info = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(context.Exception);
        info.Throw();
    }
}
```

And don't forget to replace the `IExceptionHandler` during the Web API middleware configuration:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new PassthroughExceptionHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't need to register filters both in Startup.cs and by applying attribute above the Controller class. I ended up registering it just in the Startup.cs and it worked for me.