# C# error handling in middleware does not catch error

Tags: .net

Anyhow i try when I throw exception in controller layer, this catch line does not fire.

Connecterd link [Global exception handling in OWIN middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479465/global-exception-handling-in-owin-middleware/49756864#49756864)

```
   public class GlobalExceptionMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
    {
        public GlobalExceptionMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
        { }

        public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await Next.Invoke(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I throw exception in this way:

```
public class MyController
    {
      public async Task<MyRestModel> Get(int id)
            {
                throw new Exception();
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post more code, ideally a [MCVE]. There is all kinds of things that can go wrong. Are you sure your middleware is even hit? Did you set a breakpoint?

Comment: I completed the middleware code. Yes, I set a breakpoint at  await Next.Invoke(context); and the code is stoped there. The controller throw the exception but the catch branch did not catch the exception.

Comment: So *did* you set a breakpoint on the `await Next.Invoke(context);` line? Is it hit?

Comment: Yes. It is hit.

Comment: as Dr Schizo pointed out in an comment of the top-answer of the question you linked you can not catch exceptions this way unfortunately

Comment: the problem is in Owin engine which is swallowing all exceptions by self